# What movie trailer features missing astronauts and and a bloody hand print?

Tags: story-identification

I watched a trailer of a sci-fi movie yesterday on Youtube which featured a group of astronauts going missing from their space station or ship, a typical hand blood print was shown in the trailer.

I can't seem to find that trailer or movie name anywhere. The trailer looked quite new, so I'm not sure if the movie was released yet or not.

Comment: If you watched it yesterday on youtube, did you try checking your browser or youtube history?

Comment: @phantom42 Not all of us keep active browser histories. Not all of use the same computer each day. The downvotes seem harsh for an answerable question on topic.

Answer (score 1):

It might be [Dead Space,](http://www.upcominghorrormovies.com/movie/dead-space) a new space-horror movie coming out soon.

> Set in the 26th century in deep space, where an engineer who responds to a distress signal from a mining ship finds the vessel infested with monstrous creatures called Necromorphs. The creatures are human corpses, reanimated by an alien virus.

Comment: i found it guys.its Sunshine lol and turns out ive watched itlong time back